# 'Difference between overloading and overriding', not a real question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374399) question is about difference between overloading and overriding, but I'm wondering why it is closed as not a real question. IMHO it is a clear and well defined question, even it may violate other rules that it is board or too simple.

And I found currently there are some other questions already marked as duplicate of this question, which makes the situation more complicated...

(One more wired thing to mention, this question has unexpected high view count)

Comment: Reopened.   Next time, you can just cast a custom moderator flag and explain the situation.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I am correct, or missed some points, so I ask the question to carify first

Comment: No, you didn't miss anything.  Sometimes the community gets it wrong.

Comment: It's worth mentioning "not a real question" is no longer a valid close reason, as it was commonly misused.

Comment: I would close that as 'unclear'.  I'm sure that Googling the exact title will give a huge number of good links that describe the difference.  The OP probably wants a unique answer to hand in as homework.  Since a simple Google gives what appear to be very good answers, it's unclear what the user is asking for in addition.